# Ignoring messages published by same process

Tags: masstransit

Assuming that a given endpoint does both, publishes messages of a given type for other endpoints to consume and also consumes messages of the same type published by other endpoints.

What is the best way of either not consuming or ignoring the messages published by the same endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can always check Sender's endpoint and compare it to your own, but it smells like something is conceptually wrong about this situation.